# Access class Type in static function typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following class in typescript:

```
class Parent {
    static get<T extends Parent>(): T {}
}
```

The function `get` is supposed to return and instance of type `<T extends Parent>`. For example if i have a class called `NewParent` which extends the `Parent` class, then the get function should return an object of type `NewParent`. How do i eliminate this placeholder `T` and assign the return type as the overridden class?

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is taken from [this article about obtaining a class name at runtime](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/04/obtaining-a-class-name-at-runtime-in-typescript/).

You can unpack the constructor to find the name of the instance, which works with inheritance as shown below:

```
class Describer {
    static getName(inputClass) {
        var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
        var results = (funcNameRegex).exec((<any> inputClass).constructor.toString());
        return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
    }
}

class Example {
}

class AnotherClass extends Example {
}

var x = new Example();
var y = new AnotherClass();

alert(Describer.getName(x)); // Example
alert(Describer.getName(y)); // AnotherClass
```